# jaxb throws javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Expected elements are (none) only when running in osgi bundle

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, websphere-liberty

I want to use jaxb to unmarshal xml in my liberty osgi web application.

I have a bundle with with the following code:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(serviceXmlPath);
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Service.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
return jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
```

where the Service class is in the same bundle, and I exposed an interface to the code as a service using blueprint.  Then I have another bundle with a servlet that consume it.

I unit tested the core code it was able to unmarshal correctly.  However when I ran it on webshpere liberty 8.5.5.8 in an Osgi bundle I got the following exception:

```
[err] javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Service"). Expected elements are (none)
[err]   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:660)
```

I checked to ensure when I ran with liberty it was reading the correct file and data, and that both my unit test (junit 4 from eclipse) and the server are using the same jre.  (IBM java 7 in this case.)  I am not using the jaxb feature in liberty so it should be using the one from java.

I don't understand why the code fails when running with osgi.  Could you suggest what else I should check for?

Edit:

I found out that it is a class loader issue as I printed out the class loaders and saw that JAXBContext had a different class loader than my own classes.  However changing the classloader of jaxb with the following code:

```
ClassLoader classloader = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class.getName(), classloader);
```

result in:

```
[err] javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Unable to create context
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
```

I then added a jaxb.index file to the package and the following code to print out the classloader:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Service.class);
JAXBContext jaxbContext2 = JAXBContext.newInstance();
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();   

System.out.println("classloader of Service.class:" + Service.class.getClassLoader().toString());
System.out.println("classloader of JAXBContext:" + JAXBContext.class.getClassLoader());
System.out.println("classloader of jaxbContext:" + jaxbContext.getClass().getClassLoader());
System.out.println("classloader of jaxbContext2:" + jaxbContext2.getClass().getClassLoader());
System.out.println("classloader of jaxbUnmarshaller:" + Unmarshaller.class.getClassLoader());
```

and when I run it I got:

```
classloader of Service.class:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader@b0adb798[DataService:1.0.0.qualifier(id=379)]
classloader of JAXBContext:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader@271677de[com.ibm.ws.javaee.jaxb.2.2:1.0.11.cl50820151201-1942(id=343)]
classloader of jaxbContext:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader@b997af78[com.ibm.ws.xlxp.1.5.3:1.0.11.cl50820151201-1942(id=341)]
classloader of jaxbContext2:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader@b997af78[com.ibm.ws.xlxp.1.5.3:1.0.11.cl50820151201-1942(id=341)]
classloader of jaxbUnmarshaller:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader@271677de[com.ibm.ws.javaee.jaxb.2.2:1.0.11.cl50820151201-1942(id=343)
```

Notice that it does not matters whether I pass in the class or not, it is using its own classloader  (btw, this is with jaxb2.2 enabled in liberty.  if I disable it the classloaders except for thes first one all show as null but otherwise behave the same)

Comment: How is the code you are unmarshalling from packaged?   Is it outside the bundle which 'Service' is packaged in?

Comment: (updated the question based on this comment)  In my osgi code I have my 'Service' class and unmarshalling code in one bundle that expose an interface as a service using blueprint (all in the same package). Then I have a second bundle that do a lookup on that blueprint service to invoke the call.

Comment: I would think that if your unmarshalling code is in the same bundle as your JAXB classes (**Service** and **Type**), then the reference to **Service.class**  would have resolved as you wanted it to.   Are you sure this is all in one bundle?

Comment: Also the [newInstance method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#newInstance%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29) you mentioned uses a package name (or list of names) not a class name, which explains your error. However this raises the need for jaxb.index or ObjectFactory, so JAXB knows what JAXB classes are in the package.

Comment: Maybe you should compare **this.getClass().getClassLoader()** with **Service.class.getClassLoader()** in your original example.  I don't imagine the classloader of the JAXBContext impl itself would be an issue.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  I found that I could not change the classloader at all, and have edit the post with the details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to work.  In my bundle manifest I imported the package javax.xml.bind, which I thought was all I needed since that was what I imported in the code that call the unmarshalling.  It turns out that I also need to add  javax.xml.bind.annotation since the model classes imports it.

Anyway, thanks Scott for your comments